# Konva Transformer on shape relative to parent group's x,y coords

Tags: konvajs

Is there a way to set the x,y coordinates of the `Transformer` upon instantiation?

The issue I'm having is that my shape's coordinates are relative to the parent group's coordinates, and when you create a `Transformer`, it takes the x,y values of the shape (which, again, are relative to the group it's contained in) and places it relative to the stage.

I have a drawing that illustrates the issue. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the current moment, `Konva` only support the case where `Konva.Transformer` and an attaching node are placed in the same parent element.

In your case, they have different parents.

Just move `Konva.Transformer` into the group.

Comment: That was an easy fix. Thanks for that :)